# How to add Onsubmit () functionality in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My Webpage using 1000s of the html page and its header and footers are maintained in single Javascript file.

An issue is, if any new link is opened from my web page the newly opened page is auto-refreshing.

Adding `onSubmit="return false"` in my HTML files will solve the issue. But It's not possible to add the same in 1000s of HTML files.

please let me know is there any way by which I can control this auto refreshing issue and add this functionality globally once in my Javascript file?

Comment: better to put your code here so we can see if where was the issue coming from

Comment: So all pages have import for that single javascript file? You can override onSubmit in that js file for all forms

Comment: The behavior you're describing doesn't make sense. Javascript code running on your web page cannot affect the behavior of other web pages you link to.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Show some code from one of 1000s HTML files including javascript

Comment: Guessing somewhere you're triggering a form submit in your JS causing a refresh loop - check any areas where your calling  the `submit()` method of a form. Code samples would be helpful to pinpoint and provide a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('hosted_payment_form');
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        _gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first of all find all form in page. Using following code & add onsubmit event dynamically using jQuery.

You can put this code in your common javascript file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("onsubmit", "return false");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="a.php" method="post" id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="name1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit1">
</form>

<form action="b.php" method="post" id="form2">
  <input type="text" name="name2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit2">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur clarification. if u do not mind could u please elaborate. i could not understand ur answer completly

Comment: Can you explain this? "Adding onSubmit="return false" in my html files will solve the issue.".. Where this onsubmit you are adding?